# Insert multiple row with a unique value - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-insert

i want to insert multiples rows, my first column (MATR) should be each number of the table @MATR

```
DECLARE @MATR TABLE (id INT) 
INSERT INTO @MATR values (22),(23),(99),(101)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[GPI_DOS_ANC_EXP]
           ([MATR]
           ,[ANC_APQ_YEAR]
           ,[ANC_ACQ_ENS_NB_YEAR]
           ,[ANC_ACQ_ENS_NB_DAY])
            VALUES (*Something here* ,NULL ,'0','0.00')
```

the database should look like this (22, null, 0, 0.00), (23, null, 0, 0.00), (99, null, 0, 0.00), (101, null, 0, 0.00)

I need some help please !

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[GPI_DOS_ANC_EXP] ([MATR], [ANC_APQ_YEAR], [ANC_ACQ_ENS_NB_YEAR],[ANC_ACQ_ENS_NB_DAY])
     SELECT m.id, NULL, 0, 0.00
     FROM @MATR m;
```